# Eclipse installing plugin doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I am trying to add the Android Plugin to Eclipse from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/. After entering the URL nothing happens. I already unchecked "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" but it still doesn't work.

Does someone know this behaviour?

Error:

```
Communication with repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ failed.
Communication with repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ failed.
Read timed out
```

Comment: After dozens of android plugin installs I've never had a failure....

Comment: @KevinDTimm This isn't something particular to Android Plugins, trying to load the Eclipse Marketplace also doesn't work...

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy (that prevents Eclipse to access the internet)?

Comment: I used to use a local proxy, but I don't anymore (but it still was running in background). And since I never worked on Eclipse outside of the office the internet connection always worked. I removed the settings, and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use a local proxy, but I don't anymore (but it still was running in background). And since I never worked on Eclipse outside of the office the internet connection always worked. I removed the settings, and now it works.